# JPA - Paginated query with ManyToMany collection returns wrong number of entities

Tags: jpa, pagination, many-to-many, eclipselink, jpql

I have these two entities (here are simplified versions) :

Topic :

```
@Entity
public class Topic implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Long         id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "topic_member",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "topic" ),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "member" ) )
    @JoinFetch
    private List<Member> participants   = new ArrayList<Member>();

    ...
```

Member :

```
@Entity
public class Member implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Long                id;

    ...
```

Those are related through a join table `topic_member(member, topic)`, via a unidirectionnal @ManyToMany relationship.

Everything works just fine when I insert stuff, no problem here.

But when I want to select stuff, it becomes more tricky. Let's say I want to select all the topics related to a particular member. I wrote the following JPQL query:

```
SELECT t FROM Topic t WHERE :member MEMBER OF t.participants ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

And then I wrote this:

```
TypedQuery<Topic> query = em.createQuery( MY_JPQL_REQUEST, Topic.class );
query.setParameter( PARAM_MEMBER, member );
return query.getResultList();
```

And it works just fine.

But something is very weirdly wrong : it seems I can't use pagination on this query! 
For example, when I try this:

```
TypedQuery<Topic> query = em.createQuery( MY_JPQL_REQUEST, Topic.class );
query.setParameter( PARAM_MEMBER, member );
query.setFirstResult( 0 );
query.setMaxResults( 5 );
return query.getResultList();
```

It returns me a wrong number of entities. For example, when the previous one returns 5, it returns only 3...

What am I missing here? I can't understand what could go wrong.

I've read [this page](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/321611/) and I think there may be something here, but I can't figure out what.

**[Edit] Here is what I have in the join table in the DB, if it helps:**

```
+-------------+--------------+
| member      | topic        |
+-------------+--------------+
|           1 |            1 |
|           1 |            2 |
|           1 |            3 |
|           1 |            4 |
|           1 |            5 |
|           2 |            1 |
|           2 |            2 |
|           2 |            3 |
|           2 |            4 |
|           2 |            5 |
+-------------+--------------+
```

**[Solution] Thanks to Chris, I got it working. I had to replace `@JoinFetch` by `@BatchFetch( BatchFetchType.JOIN )` on the `@ManyToMany` field, and to query `SELECT DISTINCT(t) FROM ...` instead of `SELECT t FROM ...`.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.  Pagination works at the database level to filter the number of rows returned.  When using fetch joins over collections, it requires multiple rows to build a single entity, so the number of entities returned will not match the max results.  On top of that, to ensure Bly complete entities are returned, the first and last might be discarded, since there isn't a way to verify they are complete.

Try using batch fetching with an IN strategy instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In my case, how should I use IN strategy to select all the topics related to a particular member? I tried, but I never got it to work properly.

Comment: http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_batchfetch.htm is what I was referring to instead of the join fetch annotation.  The mapping you've shown goes from topic to member, so something like "select m from topic t join t.participants m where t = :t"

Comment: Unfortunately this request seems wrong. In my simple design, each topic has a list of members, and I want all topics for a given member (= every topic where a given member is in its participants list). I must be missing something obvious, but I can't see how to do this without MEMBER OF...

Comment: batch fetch works fine with your original query.  It is the use of join fetch that causes issues with pagination.  If it still has problems, try using DISTINCT.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot! In the end, `@BatchFetch` (IN or JOIN type, both work fine) on the `@ManyToMany` field + `DISTINCT` in the JPQL query did the trick.